# Как зациклить анимацию XML

Tags: java, android, xml, анимация

Помогите пожалуйста, надо сделать анимацию, чтоб текст уменьшался, а потом снова увеличивался и это зациклить.

Уменьшение:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
android:duration="500"

   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.7"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.7"
        android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%">
    </scale>
</set>
```

Увеличение:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
  android:duration="500"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <scale
     android:fromXScale="0.7"
     android:toXScale="1.0"
     android:fromYScale="0.7"
     android:toYScale="1.0"
     android:pivotX="50%"
     android:pivotY="50%">
    </scale>
 </set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изпользуйте это `android:repeatMode="restart"` или `android:repeatMode="reverse"`

Если хотите, чтобы она туда-сюда гоняла, то юзайте реверс мод, и тогда только 1 анимацию заюзаете, она потом в обратную сторону пойдёт и так до бесконечности